# Angular 2: How to programmatically create and click a download link?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to automatically generate and fire a bunch of file "downloads".

In my template I have:

```
<a #exportLink [href]="exportUrl" [download]="exportFileName"></a>
```

In my code I set:

```
@ViewChild("exportLink") exportLink;
```

And then I generate download content from a blob and click the element:

```
this.exportUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
this.exportFileName = filename;
this.exportLink.nativeElement.click();
```

Now the problem is that apparently this click happens too soon and the DOM hasn't updated yet so it tries to download a null URL. **On the second try it works**. How can I click so that the DOM is updated? I tried to do that in `ngDoCheck()` but it failed similarily.

Comment: So add a delay to allow the DOM to render?

Comment: Yes, I might try that but it feels like a hack :)

Comment: you want to prevent from download untill the dom is updated??

Comment: Where did you put the " lines of code you pasted here? have you tried `ngAfterViewChecked`? NB: Are you using angularjs or angular2?

Comment: @StephaneM: `ngAfterViewChecked()` seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using change detection mechanism by adding the following:

1: Add [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) to your component constructor:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

2: Add `this.cdr.detectChanges()` ***before*** you fire the `click` event:

```
this.exportUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
this.exportFileName = filename;
this.cdr.detectChanges(); /* <- newly inserted line */
this.exportLink.nativeElement.click();
```